# Excel or Power BI graphing visual type

Tags: python, excel, powerbi

I am wondering if there is an Excel, Power BI or Python graphing visual to give me something like the attached image.  I've seen this a few financial presentations, and sure, it can be done manually in Excel.  But Im wondering if it can be a dynamic chart based on a feed of data...[image]

I'm not aware of anything out there that will provide this automatically based on data metrics.

Comment: You can probably achieve this with a stacked bar chart with some data manipulation. Update the question with sample table of what the data feed could look like.